# How can I get around this mysql missing error on ubuntu server

Tags: php, html, browser

i just moved a website to a linode ubuntu server. This is an old php CMS - OpenGoo. Finally got the code and db files straighten out, or so I thought, but now when I start through the install process, i get the msg below:

```
Step 2: Environment checks
OK: PHP version is 7.4.3
**Error: 'mysql' extension is not loaded**
OK: 'gd' extension is loaded
OK: 'simplexml' extension is loaded
OK: /config is writable
OK: /cache is writable
OK: /upload is writable
OK: /tmp is writable
```

this is an older application that was around during php5 i think.  Is there any way to get around/past this error.  I can't roll the server back to php5 .

Any help on what I should check would be very helpful and appreciated.

Happy New Year everyone!!!

Comment: The `mysql_*()` functions were removed as of PHP7. Your application won't run with anything later than PHP 5.6 unless you want to spend an unreasonable amount of time updating it.

Comment: An afterthought: OpenGoo has become [Feng Office](https://fengoffice.com/). There might be an upgrade path.

Comment: Thank so much @TangentiallyPerpendicular, i will dig in to Feng Office - thanks again.  Happy New Year!